# Why my Lua table is error when l use while loop

Tags: debugging, lua

here is my error

```
Expected objects to be the same.
Passed in:
(table) {
  [1] = 1
  [2] = 2
  [3] = 3
  [4] = 4 }
Expected:
(nil)
```

here is my code some one can help me please

```
local function between(a, b)
  local table = {}
  while not a == 5 do
    local a = 1
    table[a] = a
    local a = a + 1
  end
  print(table)
end

return between
```

l have tried to use for loop
can someone help me please

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you're calling the function. The first problem I see is that `not a` will always be `true` or `false`, neither of which is equal to 5, so the loop won't run.

Comment: You should read a Lua tutorial about local variable's scope in Lua.

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues with the loop that need to be fixed to make it work:

```lua
local function between(a, b)
  local table = {}
  while a > 0 do
    -- local a = 1 -- this is not needed, as it:
    -- (1) creates a *new* `a` value, which shadows the original value without changing it
    -- (2) is reset every loop iteration without any impact on the `a` value above
    table[a] = a
    -- local a = a + 1 -- this creates yet another `a` variable that is only visible
    -- inside the loop, so doesn't have any impact on the `while` condition

    -- since you already have the number of iterations you want to do (`a`)
    -- you can simply keep subtracting from it until it reaches 0:
    a = a - 1
  end
  -- it's better to return the value, as you may do something other than printing
  return table
end
```

This should work, but in those cases when you know the number of iterations, it's better to use the `for` loop instead of the `while` loop, as it takes care of increasing/decreasing your loop variable:

```lua
local tbl = {}
for i = 1, a do tbl[i] = i end
return tbl
```

You should avoid using `table` as a variable name, as it clashes with the table value already provided by Lua.

Comment: @IHML, You can approve the answer if it works for you.